# Wordpress wp-admin css not loading

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

> previously its have SSL now don't have SSL

my WordPress admin dashboard is not loading CSS but the home page and other pages are working perfectly anyone knows how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: check the browser console (look for 404)

Comment: Check your website settings that the website is pointing to the correct address (including http) - https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/